# Processing a generated tree dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have the following tree structure. The aim is to construct a table in the database using postgresql query. 
The table should contains the following information. The first column contains the node.
 And the second contains the parent node.

```
                  |--node1.1.1          
       |-node1.1--|                
       |          |--node1.1.2           
       |                
       |                
       |             
node1--|-node1.2--|--node1.2.1   
       |          
       |                
       |                
       |           
       |-node1.3
```

Table tree:
[image]

Below you find the query that will generate the initial table:

```
CREATE TABLE tree
( node character varying NOT NULL,
  node_parent character varying,
  CONSTRAINT tree_pkey PRIMARY KEY (node),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ FOREIGN KEY (node_parent)
      REFERENCES tree (node) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tree
  OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1', null);
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.1', 'node1');
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.2', 'node1');
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.3', 'node1');
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.1.1', 'node1.1');
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.1.2', 'node1.1');
INSERT INTO tree(node, node_parent) VALUES ('node1.2.1', 'node1.2');
```

Then from this table (tree) we aim to generate the following table. The query should return for each composed node the list of subnodes. This query should generate a resultswhich are semilar to the example below. 
To do this we have proposed the following query.

```
SELECT node, node_parent   FROM tree t where   not (node  in(select distinct              node_parent from tree where  not node_parent is null))
union all
SELECT tn2.node, tn1.node_parent FROM tree tn1 join tree tn2 on tn1.node =     tn2.node_parent  where not tn1.node_parent is null and not (tn2.node  in(select      distinct node_parent from tree where  not node_parent is null))
```

Result :

[image]

The problem with the query that we have proposed is that it is not generic and  does not work for all cases (this query work only for the case where we have a tree with depth equals to three). We want to have a query that work in all cases.

Comment: Do you have a fixed depth of children?

Comment: `WITH RECURSIVE t AS (SELECT node from tree t0 where t0.node_parent = NULL UNION ALL select  select t1.node from tree t1 JOIN t ON t.node= t1.parent_node) SELECT * FROM t;`

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO thanks, the depth is not fixed in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for all your contributions. Thanks to that we have succeeded to solve the issue as follow:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy(node, node_parent) AS (
               SELECT node, node_parent
FROM tree 
            UNION ALL
             SELECT t.node, h.node_parent
               FROM hierarchy h
                 JOIN tree t ON h.node = t.node_parent
            )
     SELECT *
       FROM hierarchy 
   WHERE NOT (node IN ( SELECT node_parent  FROM tree where not node_parent is null)) and not node_parent is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [with statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). Your final query will look like the following.

```
with recursive hierarchy(node, node_parent, level) as (
    select node, node_parent, 0
    from tree
    where node_parent is null
    union all
    select t.node, t.node_parent, level + 1
    from tree t
        join hierarchy h on t.node_parent = h.node)
select *
from hierarchy;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the solution that you propose gives results different from the results that we have provided.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with standard sql to create queries with variable depth.

So you can follow one of the following ways:

- Create a function that take two nodes and returns true if they are relatives (so if it is possible to go from node1 to node2 passing parent by parent. And use this function in the query.
- Use a recursive query
- Change database and instead of a standard relational database use a graph database that can natively offer functions to navigate the whole graph without limits on the depth.

Note that the first two options can be very heavy because a relational database is not written for such kind of queries.

Comment: You say "it is not possible", yet you give the solution: a recursive query (which **is** standard SQL). Recursive queries are pretty efficient in modern databases

Comment: Is not standard sql. It is dialect of postgres

Comment: It is **not** a dialect of Postgres. Recursive common table expressions have been part of the SQL standard for over 10 years now (since 2003). They are also nothing special to Postgres, and they are supported by a wide range of DBMS, e.g. Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Firebird, SAP HANA and many others

Comment: @horse interesting I was quite sure that different vendors implemented similar function but no standard was defined. Thanks

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO thanks for the explanation and fruitful discussion. In fact, we are investigating the use of recursive functions to solve the issue.